# Can't dispose of service because Data Annotation Validation interrupt further logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller, litedb

I have a service that should perform persistent logic and is being used with dependency injection as Transient
Every time this implementation is called it should read or create a database file, and LiteDB needs to perform disposal.

```cs
public class VendaService : IVendaService<LiteDatabase> {
    public readonly LiteDatabase _dbContext;
    public readonly ILiteCollection<Venda> collection;
    
     public VendaService() {
        //read or create a collection in the path passed.
        _dbContext = new LiteDatabase(...);

        //read or create a collection of <T> 
        collection = _dbContext.GetCollection<Venda>("vendas");

        //creates the first bulk of sample data if it doesn't exist data.
        if(collection.Count() == 0){...};
    }

    public async Task<Venda> PostVendaService(Vendedor vendedor, List<Item> carrinho) {
        Venda doc = new Venda() {...};
        var collection = _dbContext.GetCollection<Venda>("vendas");
        collection.Insert(doc);

        _dbContext.Dispose();

        return doc;
    }
}
```

The service is being called in the controller's constructor because the methods aren't being called upon data annotation validation error occurs, it couldn't dispose, which blocks future calls.

```cs
[HttpPost("api")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostVenda(PostVendaRequestModel postRequest) 
{
     if (postRequest.carrinho.Count == 0){...}

     foreach (Item item in postRequest.carrinho){...}

     Venda postVenda = await _vendaService.PostVendaService(
          vendedor: postRequest.vendedor,
          carrinho: postRequest.carrinho);

     return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetVendaById), new { id = postVenda.VendaId.ToString() }, postVenda);
}

[BindProperties]
public class PostVendaRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    public Vendedor vendedor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Item> carrinho { get; set; }
}
```

[Edited]
Trying to dispose inside the constructor of VendaService can't solve either, this also showed a problem that every further validation outside of the methods would make it unable to call `_db.Dispose()`. SO I'm at a loss how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @Yuri Soares, so why not handling the model validation error?

Comment: @Rena Honestly I don't know, I'm completely new at C# and .NET . I though of not instantiate LiteDatabase() in the constructor of the service, but rather handle it at every method of service methods. Any resource for broad knowledge at this aspect is welcome.